# В Visual Studio Express 2015 for Windows Desktop отсутствует файл шаблона создания диаграммы классов

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Не могу создать файл диаграммы классов в Visual Studio 2015 - нет шаблона с расширением .cd
Вот скрины всего содержания предлагаемых шаблонов. Диаграммы - нет!

Comment: Visual C#->Общие->Схема классов (или аналогичный путь на английском) Отсутствует?
Что за издание? (Community/Professional/ ect)

Comment: Контекстное меню проекта-> перейти к схеме классов тоже отсутствует? Искомый Class Diagram должен быть выше в списке (если опираться на скрин) его там нет?

Comment: go to class diagram - такого нет

Comment: 5 раз прошел внимательно по списку предлагаемых шаблонов - нет его

Comment: Судя по скрину - VS 2015 Express, в этой редакции точно есть возможность построения диаграмм классов?

Comment: Запустите установщик студии. Выберите вариант Modify. Поищите в списке доступных для установки компонентов модули которые могут добавлять возможность создания диаграммы классов в студию. Если не поможет - попробуйте Repair. Если нет и у вас Express версия- скорее всего функционал не поддерживается. В противном случае попробуйте переустановить студию.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую переустановить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я верно расcмотрел скриншот, то в используемой версии Visual Studio создание диаграмм классов [не поддерживается](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/).
Попробуйте использовать как минимум Community Edition ибо судя по [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491389/does-visual-studio-2013-express-support-the-class-designer-feature) - в Express редакции такой возможности нет. Но там речь идет о 2013 версии. Вряд ли в 2015 в этом отношении что-то поменялось.

**UPD.**

В комментарии автор вопроса говорит, что в версии Visual Studio **Community Edition** есть возможность работы с диаграммами классов.

Comment: переустановил  на версию Community - в ней есть class Diagram

Comment: @Proshka, отлично! Обновил ответ. Спасибо за комментарий!